# Animation does not play when changing display

Tags: css, css-animations

I wanted to make an animation, but it's not smooth. When I removed display - everything worked fine. How to do with display and smoothly?

```css
div {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: opacity 3s;
  background-color: black;
}

input:checked + div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `visibility` & `position` instead of `display`

```css
div {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 3s;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

input:checked+div {
  visibility: visible;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">

<div></div><span>&lt;space&gt;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="name" id="name" />

<div id="animation">
   test
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#animation').hide();

$('#trending').click(function(){
    $('#animation').fadeToggle();
})
```

Comment: I need pure CSS

Comment: As your request. I've added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```css
  div {width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 0.45s;
}

input:checked + div {
 opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but no. I do not need to change the background, I need to smoothly show the block

Comment: Can you use `visibility:hidden;` instead of `display:none;`, By the way i have updated my answer please check now

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<div class="overlay"> 
    <label for="toggle">Click to deactivate</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity ease-in 0.6s;
}
#toggle:checked ~ .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```